# PHP MySQL query shows wrong datetime in result

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I am using workbench for accessing DB connection.

My problem is when I am running the direct query in workbench the result is correct but same query I am running using PHP function the DateTime is different.
MySQL server timezone: EST
Linux Server timezone: EST

but the result comes in GMT timezone.

All the data entry records show EST time.

eg. 
Mysql Workbench result: datetime: 19:00:00
PHP query result: 22:00:00

Comment: Try to change php default time zone then execute the query

Comment: I already did that. When I am printing localtime it shows correct time

Comment: please give me 2 datetime one in GMT and other in EST ( expected output)

Comment: if MySQL datetime=10/10/2017 00:00:00(Stored in DB) then PHP is returning 04:00:00.(Returning after query excecution)

Answer (score 1):

Well , you can convert returned data to other timezone so if your time stored in EST but php showing it as GMT , you can convert it again

here is an example

```
// now
$date = date_create('2017-10-09 07:00:00', timezone_open('Asia/Dubai'));

function getDateByTimeZone($date,$TimeZone='US/Eastern'){
    date_timezone_set($date, timezone_open($TimeZone));
    return $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
echo getDateByTimeZone($date);
echo "<br />";
echo getDateByTimeZone($date,'GMT');

// Output 

# 2017-10-08 23:00:00
# 2017-10-09 03:00:00

?>
```

assume `$date` is your returned data from Mysql which is in your case GMT , pass it to that function then you will get EST .

**Also you can configure your PHP.init file by changing the following**

```
date.timezone = "America/New_York"
```

and to make sure your php server is running under correct timezone

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

you will find `Default timezone` in `Date Section`
from that information you should be able to see default timezone for your php server .

if you want to set Default timezone for single website in your server you can edit `VirtualHost` by adding the following

```
<IfModule php7_module>
php_admin_value date.timezone "America/New_York"
</IfModule>
<IfModule php5_module>
php_admin_value date.timezone "America/New_York"
</IfModule>
```

if you would like to set default timezone per folder you could edit **htaccess** file by adding the following

```
<IfModule !fcgid_module>
php_value date.timezone "America/New_York"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: yes, That I am using for a temporary solution. but I want to know why this happening. My local time of PHP is already in EST format and my SQL server is also storing EST time then why PHP is passing UTC time.

Comment: what is the output of 
echo  date_default_timezone_get().'<br />';

Comment: America/New_York

Comment: check my new answer pls

Comment: Nope. Still facing the same issue. I have to use temporary Timezone conversion for time issue.